# How does the mission 'I demand all products stocked on 5 level(s)' work?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I am currently on this mission:

[image: Mission]

Does this mean that I have to stock 5 levels at the same time?

I have received a fully stocked bonus with only two workers before... Does this count towards this mission? ( I assume not)....

*I only ask as I have been stuck on this mission for some time now (and it does not show any progress)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to have five levels, all of which are fully stocked (3 items being sold), at the same time.

Comment: It also doesn't count any levels that are already fully stocked; their final item-stocking has to occur after the mission has been started.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have to be the same time. If you just use the same floor and restock it then that would work too. The workout center does. This pretty easily.

Comment: I'm fairly certain it must be at the same time. Although, that might just be for the 3 levels version of this quest.

Comment: Well I had started over a couple days ago and did the quest and I used the workout center twice to complete the mission. That's how I came up with that.